# Massachusetts sales tax on clothing

Tags: square-connect

Is there a way to process Massachusetts clothing tax with square-connect?  For each item of clothing sold, MA sales tax is 0% on the first $175 and 6.25% on the price above $175.  This rule applies separately to each item of clothing, so if all the items on a sale are each $175 or less then there will be no tax even if the total is over $175.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the Square Connect API (or any other Square method). Currently, taxes applied with Square must be applied to the entirety of an item's cost.

I've passed this use case along to the Connect API engineering team.